# How to open web page without WebBrowser control in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, overlay

I am new to c#, I want to open web page in c# without using WebBrowser control or asp.net contol because my app is supposed to run on smart tv which would not support asp.net control,IS there any technique using which I can capture the contents of the webkit and render them on the image..As far as i have researched Only C# can capture the contents of the webkit..Any pointers in the right direction will be really appreciated.
[image]

Actually I want to achive as depicted in the screen shot web page over image

Comment: Im sure smart tv's have their own web browser, why not just open web pages in that?

Comment: @Sayse : But i want to render the web page or image  in my own app

Comment: @Sayse : is there any possibility to render web page over layered winForm